# DialogBox in addon for Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-addon

I'm trying to display a `DialogBox` from a function used in an addon for Google Form.

```
function onOpen() {
  FormApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('MyAddon')
    .addItem('Test', 'myTest')
    .addToUi();
}

function myTest() {
  Logger.log("--> called");

  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); // or UiApp.getActiveApplication()
  var dialog = app.createDialogBox();
  dialog.setPopupPosition(100, 100).setSize(500, 500);
  dialog.show();
  return app;
}
```

Unlike `FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(content, title)`, function using `DialogBox` is called but does nothing (nothing is displayed).
Does anyone succeed in displaying such component in a Google addon?

Goal of using `DialogBox` is to be able to set a close handler, which is not possible using `.showModalDialog(...)` (which returns `void` but not reference to created dialog).

I don't see any other way in Google API for UI in addon to display a dialog, with a callback when it's closed.

Comment: UiApp is deprecated since December 2014. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app

Answer (score -1):

Calling this function from server side code (which is what happens when that menu item is selected) will not display this Ui if it is just returned from the function. You need to use a method such as `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(uiInstance, 'My add-on');` to have it display for the user.

If all you're looking for is a way to take action once the dialog is closed, consider using [alert dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs) or [prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs). These will return an object which can be queried to see which button the user selected, or what text was entered in the dialog.

Comment: As said `showModalDialog(...)` is not applicable + tested code is not only returning ui but call `show()` on `DialogBox`, as on Google documentation (which is not working currently).

Comment: Those links actually point to the methods ui.alert() and ui.prompt(), not showModalDialog(). Can you use those methods, or do you need to show a custom dialog?

Comment: As said, function displaying predefined dialog are not applicable.